# How to extract middle portion of file name to create new file name?

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a new file name from the default file name created from its source program.

I need to add a revision to the end of the filename, but also add a prefix to the beginning of the default filename.

The default filename looks as follows: `drw1234567_1.dxf`.

I need to change it to `1234567_drw1234567_1Rev0A.dxf`.

I have been able to create the "REVISION" and "PAGE" parameter in my script, but cannot get the "PART_NUMBER". Any help would be much appreciated!

```
rem extract_revision_parameter.BAT
REM // Parse drawing_parameter file for revision number
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%a IN (`find "REVISION" C:\dxf\in\draw_parameter*.txt`) DO SET REVISION=Rev%%a
FOR %%a IN ( C:\dxf\in\*.DXF) DO (SET %%a)
pause
REM // Retrieve page number with underscore from file name by 
REM //skipping the first 7 digits that represent the part number
FOR %%i IN (C:\dxf\in\*.dxf) DO (
    REM //Retrieve file name without .dxf extension
    SET NAME=%%~ni
)
pause
REM //The line bellow needs to be done outside the for loop for some reason...
SET PAGE=%NAME:~10%
pause
REM // Rename file to standard file name
REN c:\dxf\in\drw*.dxf %PART_NUMBER%_drw%PART_NUMBER%%PAGE%%REVISION%_dxf.dxf
REM // Move the renamed .dxf to the C:\dxf\out\ folder
MOVE /Y "C:\dxf\in\*.dxf" "C:\dxf\out\"
REM // clean up in folder of *.txt and *.log files
DEL "C:\dxf\in\*.txt"
DEL "C:\dxf\in\*.log*"
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description - it appears you only need to add a prefix and suffix to the actual file name and preserve the extension. This being the case, you can do this relatively easy by updating the relevant portion of your code:

```
REM Add this to the top of your script.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Other code goes here...

REM Use the DIR command output so files to process are loaded in memory.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i IN (`DIR "C:\dxf\in\*.dxf" /B`) DO (
    SET NAME=%%~ni
    SET Extension=%%~xi
    REM Rename the file by prefixing with the part number and suffixing with the revision.
    RENAME "%%~fi" "%PART_NUMBER%!NAME!%REVISION%!Extension!"
)

REM Other code goes here...

REM Add this to the end.
ENDLOCAL
```

The `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` allows you to use variables you set within the context of each loop iteration. Since you did not have this specified on your script, that is why the `NAME` variable was only available outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! I ended up getting it working. I will add the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion to get the NAME inside the loop.